# Multiple "and" conditions in jquery if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've run alerts for each of the variables.  It appears that they equal the values below.  I'm assuming I've missed something with the writing of the if statement since I'm fairly new to jquery.  Thanks!

the html are all inputs...

```
<input value="10" size="2" readonly>
```

defining variables...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var arrivalMonth = $('input').eq(29).val();
var arrivalDay = $('input').eq(30).val();
var arrivalYear = $('input').eq(31).val();
var departureMonth = $('input').eq(32).val();
var departureDay = $('input').eq(33).val();
var departureYear = $('input').eq(34).val();
```

and...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if (arrivalMonth === '10' && arrivalDay === '10' && arrivalYear === '2015' && departureMonth === '10' && departureDay === '10' && departureYear === '2015') { 
        alert("YES");  
    }
});
```

Comment: Are the variables of the same type? ie. are you comparing `int` to `string`?

Comment: It would help to see the rest of the code (like where `firstMonth` etc are defined).

Comment: updated w/ additional code being used... thanks!

Comment: Updated answer. You need to supply the *full code* as it is ambiguous as to whether you have one or 2 separate DOM ready handlers.

Comment: Curious, got it to work if I don't assign variables... if( $('input').eq(29).val() == 10 && $('input').eq(30).val() == 10 && $('input').eq(31).val() == 2015 && $('input').eq(32).val() == 10 && $('input').eq(33).val() == 10 && $('input').eq(34).val() == 2015 )

Comment: Which would indicate TrueBlue's answer is correct.

Comment: correct... got it working... thank you for setting me straight

Answer (score 3):

`===` also checks that the variable is the same type.

e.g. if the values are of type `number` that will not match a string value (even if it appears to be the same thing).

e.g. `10 === "10"` => false;

Change to `==` to test as that will then coerce the values to the same type.

If they are numbers, try:

```
if (firstMonth === 10 && firstDay === 10 && firstYear === 2015 && secondMonth === 10 && secondDay === 10 && secondYear === 2015) { 
    alert("YES");  
}
```

As it happens, you are using `val()` to get the variables, so they will be of type number as `val` will auto-convert numeric characters to numbers. In any case, safer to use `==` here.

It is not clear exactly how your DOM ready handlers relate, but if you are defining your variables inside a *second* DOM ready handler then they are not visible to the rest of your code at all. Basically they would all be "undefined".

Move them into the same scope,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var arrivalMonth = $('input').eq(29).val();
    var arrivalDay = $('input').eq(30).val();
    var arrivalYear = $('input').eq(31).val();
    var departureMonth = $('input').eq(32).val();
    var departureDay = $('input').eq(33).val();
    var departureYear = $('input').eq(34).val();
    if (arrivalMonth == 10 && arrivalDay == 10 && arrivalYear == 2015 && departureMonth == 10 && departureDay == 10 && departureYear == 2015) { 
        alert("YES");  
    }
});
```

or out into the global scope.

```
var arrivalMonth;
var arrivalDay;
var arrivalYear;
var departureMonth;
var departureDay;
var departureYear;

$(document).ready(function() { 
    arrivalMonth = $('input').eq(29).val();
    arrivalDay = $('input').eq(30).val();
    arrivalYear = $('input').eq(31).val();
    departureMonth = $('input').eq(32).val();
    departureDay = $('input').eq(33).val();
    departureYear = $('input').eq(34).val();
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    if (arrivalMonth == 10 && arrivalDay == 10 && arrivalYear == 2015 && departureMonth == 10 && departureDay == 10 && departureYear == 2015) { 
        alert("YES");  
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm... neither of those suggestions seemed to work.  attempted === 10, =="10", and ==="10".  I also added to my original question to clarify above.  Thanks

Comment: @odyssey82: Updated code to match your own code update.